# Efficient way to handle multiple if statement with the same connection to PDO mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I would like to ask what is the efficient way to deal with these code. im checking changes in the form and if there are changes it store to DB. is there a way to convert 4 if statement into one. thanks

```
if ($_REQUEST['hidden_value_of_input_box1'] !== $newvalueofinputbox1) {    

    $data = "Input Box 1 has been changed";

    $name = $name;   
    $date = $datenow;    
    $stm = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO audit SET name=:name, datenow=:datenow, data=:data");     
    $stm->bindParam(':name', $name);   $stm->bindParam(':value', $value);   
    $stm->execute(); 
}  

if ($_REQUEST['hidden_value_of_input_box2'] !== $newvalueofinputbox2) {    

    $data = "Input Box 2 has been changed";

    $name = $name;   
    $date = $datenow;    
    $stm = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO audit SET name=:name, datenow=:datenow, data=:data");     
    $stm->bindParam(':name', $name);   $stm->bindParam(':value', $value);   $stm->execute(); 
}  

if ($_REQUEST['hidden_value_of_dropdown1'] !== $newvalueofdropdown1) {    

    $data = "Drop Down 1 has been changed";    

    $name = $name;   
    $date = $datenow;    
    $stm = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO audit SET name=:name, datenow=:datenow, data=:data");     
    $stm->bindParam(':name', $name);   $stm->bindParam(':value', $value);   $stm->execute(); 
}  

if ($_REQUEST['hidden_value_of_dropdown2'] !== $newvalueofdropdown2) {    

    $data = "Drop Down 2 has been changed";   

    $name = $name;   
    $date = $datenow;    
    $stm = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO audit SET name=:name, datenow=:datenow, data=:data");     
    $stm->bindParam(':name', $name);   
    $stm->bindParam(':value', $value);   
    $stm->execute(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on the form:

```
<input name="hidden_value_of_input_box[]" type="hidden" value="anyvalue">
<input name="hidden_value_of_input_box[]" type="hidden" value="anyvalue">
<input name="hidden_value_of_input_box[]" type="hidden" value="anyvalue">
```

on the submition and processing:

```
<?php
foreach($_POST["hidden_value_of_input_box"] as $value){
echo $value;
}
?>
```

something like that. :)

Answer (score 0):

return the input field as an array and then loop on those values then in that manner your code would be even more shorter, simpler and dynamic. :)